# "Wear Uniform Clothes"

Tags: word-choice, nouns

If I ask a pupil about what clothes he wears to school, which is correct?

> Do you wear a uniform to go to school?
>   Do you wear uniform clothes to go to school?

Comment: Simply uniform will do

Answer (score 11):

The correct sentence is

> Do you wear a uniform to go to school?

In fact you can simply say

> Do you wear a uniform to school?

in this case.

Comment: +1. Uniform as an adjective doesn't mean exactly the same thing as a noun. "a uniform" is a prescribed outfit. "uniform clothes" might mean "clothing that is part of a uniform" or "clothing that is all the same".

Comment: I think even more common is simply **Do you wear school uniform?**

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Shouldn't it be "Do you wear *a* school uniform?" or "Do you wear *the* school uniform?" ?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: [Here](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=wear+school+uniform&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) are plenty of written instances that don't use an article. Plus several upvotes for my comment surely prove that many of us are quite happy with the usage, which I don't think is any less "formal" than your alternatives.